# JDBC Embedded-Database with Sybase dialect

Tags: hibernate, spring, jdbc, embedded-database

How can I set a JDBC embedded-database to use the Sybase dialect?

Here is what I have:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
   <jdbc:script location="classpath:myscript.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Comment: dialect is something from Hibernate/JPA world, how is it related to embedding a database? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Use an embedded database to using test DAO code in a project that uses Spring, Hibernate and a Sybase DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Spring supports H2, Derby, and HSQL embedded databases.  If you want to use a different one, you will either have to find someone who has already created support for the one you are looking for, or else you will have to build it on your own.

If you take a look at [13.8.4 of the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support), they provide the extension points which you could implement to do it yourself (via [`EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.html) or [`DataSourceFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/DataSourceFactory.html)).  I would also recommend browsing their [Jira page](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) to see if anyone is working on implementing support for the embedded database you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Again, dialect is something Hibernate-related. It is defined as a property of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`:

```
<bean id="exampleSessionFactory" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect</prop>
         ...
```

But Sybase dialect doesn't mean that the database that it's used against is Sybase. You are free to try to use Sybase dialect with the three embedded databases bundled with Spring @nicholas.hauschild mentioned, but it will most probably fail.

Comment: Ok, right. However the problem is that the config in the post fails because the embedded-database is not using the Sybase dialect to run the setup scripts.

Comment: what do you mean by _not using_ ?

Comment: Meaning that the embedded-database is not accepting Sybase dialect sql. So I am having to translate the script to non-sybase-specific syntax.